# SQL Sort by group size

Tags: sql

I want to make a select query which groups rows based on a given column and then sorts by size of such groups.

Let's say we have this sample data:

```
id type
1   c
2   b
3   b
4   a
5   c
6   b
```

**I want to obtain the following** by grouping and sorting the column 'type' in a descending way:

```
id type
2   b
3   b
6   b
1   c
5   c
4   a
```

As of now I am only able to get the count of each group but that is not exactly what I need:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(type) AS typecount
FROM sampletable
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY typecount DESC, type ASC

id type count
2   b    3
1   c    2
4   a    1
```

Can anybody please give me a hand with this query?

Edit:
Made 'b' the biggest group to avoid coming to the same solution by using only SORT BY

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the best way, but it will give you what you want.

You work out the totals for each group and then join that "virtual" table to your original table by the determined counts.

```
SELECT *
FROM sampletable s1
INNER JOIN (SELECT count(type) AS iCount,type
        FROM sampletable
        GROUP BY type) s2 ON s2.type = s1.type
ORDER BY s2.iCount DESC, s1.type ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6b0c4/6/0

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a column alias in your `GROUP BY`; just repeat the expression:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(type) AS count 
FROM sampletable 
GROUP BY type 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, type ASC
```

Note that I changed the `SELECT` clause - you can't use `*` in your `SELECT` either since expressions in the `SELECT` need to either be in the `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply D Stanley, I run your query and obtain the same result, just without 'id'. In addition, I will rename the alias 'count' to avoid ambiguity with COUNT(type).

Comment: Well, _some_ systems allow non-aggregated columns, but the results may not be determinable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform `GROUP BY` operation on `COLUMN ALIAS`.

The reason why you can't use ALIAS on the GROUP BY clause that is created on the same level of the SELECT statement is because the GROUP BY is executed before the SELECT clause in which the ALIAS is created.

This is the SQL Order of Operation:

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

Try following query:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(type) AS count 
FROM sampletable 
GROUP BY type 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, type ASC;
```

**EDIT:-**

```
SELECT id, type 
FROM sampletable  
ORDER BY type DESC, id ASC;
```

Comment: Probably my example is a bit ambiguous. There will be some times in which ordering by type is not enough. The sorting criteria is by size of groups.